# Checking if string contains multiple letters

Tags: c#

I have a collection of an object called dictionaryWords.

For each word in this collection I need to check if it does not contain certain letters. If it does contain one or more of a certain letter it is removed from the collection.

Example:

```
Collection before removal: ['abc','dee',fff']
letters to check for: e,f
Collection after removal: ['abc']
```

Rather than specifying multiple letters is there a way to check against an array?

My code:

```
foreach(DictionaryWord word in dictionaryWords)
{
    if (!word.Contains("D") && !word.Contains("E") // optimize this line
    {
        // Word does not contain letters, word is good
    }
}
```

How can I replace the "optimize this line" to say "if word contains any letter from an array of values"

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// isolate the letters
string[] letters = new string[] { "D", "E", "F" }; // other strings or letters

// interate between your data
foreach(DictionaryWord word in dictionaryWords)
{
    // check if the work does not contain any letter
    if (!letters.Any(x => word.Contains(x))
    {
        // Word does not contain letters, word is good
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not abstract this out to a function?

```
void CheckForLetters(IEnumerable<DictionaryWord> source, IEnumerable<char> letters) {
  foreach (var word in source) { 
    if (letters.any(c => word.Contains(c)) { 
      // It has the letter
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that accepts an array of characters to compare against.

The prototype would look like the following: `bool isLetterInWord(DictionaryWord word, char[] letters);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can map your `DictionaryWord` class to a string, you can use a Linq query for this:

```
var words = new string[] { "abc", "def", "fe" };
var lettersToExclude = new char[] { 'e', 'f' };
var goodWords = from x in words where !lettersToExclude.Intersect(x).Any() select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HashSets and make use of IsSubsetOf method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 string str = "teststing";

 var strset = new HashSet<char>(str.ToCharArray());
 var charstoCheck = new HashSet<char>(new Char[] {'z'});
 bool isstrcontainschars = charstoCheck.IsSubsetOf(strset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Regex` for that.

```
string value = "abcdef";
var result = new Regex("[d-e-f]").Replace(value, string.Empty);
```

It checks if the string contains the letters at the Regex's constructor, and replace the letters for what you want. In my example, I replaced the letter to `string.Empty`.

In your case, you could do like this:

```
if (new Regex("[d-e-f]").IsMatch(word))
{
    //Do something.
}
```